# Sorting Alphanumeric Values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with data consisting of

```
Item No. (1a)
Item No. (2)
Item No. (3)
Item No. (4)
Item No. (5)
Item No. (6)
Item No. (7)
Item No. (8)
Item No. (9)
Item No. (10)
```

Now assuming these are not always in this perfect order, I would like it so that when I select them, they pull in this order. However, when I do a select and try to order by anything, it gives me this

```
Item No. (1a)
Item No. (10)
Item No. (2)
Item No. (3)
Item No. (4)
Item No. (5)
Item No. (6)
Item No. (7)
Item No. (8)
Item No. (9)
```

Could anyone assist me in the sql order by statement that would give me the first order set?

Comment: how `10` can come before `2` when the whole result set seems to be in an ascending order?

Comment: Well I tried a few things, like casting it as varbinary, just regular Order By XXX ASC, they give me different results, but for the most part 10 will end up before 2

Comment: in an alpha sort, they're compared character to character.  1 comes before 2.  it's not "10" and "2" it's "1" and "2" that are being compared.  You want something that first finds the number portion, sorted by number, and then sorted by the alpha characters that proceed it.  This could change of course if all of your data doesn't match the pattern posted.  If you were to find `(` and pull all characters after until reaching a `A-Z`, sort that numerically (cast to number), and then sort the following alphabetically, that should get you the result you want.

Comment: or better off, split your column into an "number" and "sub category" (or whatever) columns, so you don't have to go though all this messy string splitting in order to accomplish a sort.  Depending on the size of the table, this will potentially be craptastic performant wise - compared to doing it the right way i mean

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pattern splitter that will split out the numeric components of the string. Here is one from from Dwain Camps' [article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/).

```
-- PatternSplitCM will split a string based on a pattern of the form 
-- supported by LIKE and PATINDEX 
-- 
-- Created by: Chris Morris 12-Oct-2012 
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[PatternSplitCM]
(
       @List                VARCHAR(8000) = NULL
       ,@Pattern            VARCHAR(50)
) RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 

RETURN
    WITH numbers AS (
      SELECT TOP(ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@List), 0))
       n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
      FROM
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d (n),
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) e (n),
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) f (n),
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) g (n))

    SELECT
      ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(n)),
      Item = SUBSTRING(@List,MIN(n),1+MAX(n)-MIN(n)),
      [Matched]
     FROM (
      SELECT n, y.[Matched], Grouper = n - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY y.[Matched],n)
      FROM numbers
      CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT [Matched] = CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@List,n,1) LIKE @Pattern THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) y
     ) d
     GROUP BY [Matched], Grouper
```

Now that you have your splitter, you can use it then to sort your data:

```
SELECT t.val
FROM tbl t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 CAST(Item AS INT)
    FROM dbo.PatternSplitCM(t.val, '%[0-9]%')
    WHERE Matched = 1
    ORDER BY ItemNumber
)s(n)
ORDER BY s.n
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/45eef/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as(
select '1a' as num
union select '2'
union select '3'
union select '4'
union select '5'
union select '6'
union select '7'
union select '8'
union select '9'
union select '10') select num from cte order by case when ISNUMERIC(num) = 0 then 0 else convert(int,num) end asc
```

The trick is in order by case when isnumeric(num) = 0 then 0 else convert(int,num) end asc.